# Calling python from node doesn't log to file

Tags: python, node.js, logging

I am using the following to run a python file

```
require('child_process').exec(`python ${__dirname}/python/script.py`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {})
```

and in the python file I have this:

```
import logging    
from os import path
from sys import argv

logging.basicConfig(filename=path.dirname(path.realpath(argv[0])) + '/../log/script.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('Hello World')
```

when I run the python script manually from any folder it logs to the file normally, but when I call it from node it doesn't

**EDIT** The python script runs correctly in both cases

Comment: If your problem is solved, mark the answer that solved it as solved, or write  your own answer if you have another solution.

Comment: The python script runs correctly in both cases, it's the logging that doesn't work when called from node

Comment: Can you check if the user which call the child process has access to write to that folder? Try writing to a folder in /tmp will all permissions given

Answer (score 0):

@Coeus, Have you found answer to this problem? I was not able to check the python script's error while calling it from my Express/Node app. So instead of spawning threads using standart NodeJS lib, I used `npm` [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell). I could see the Python script's trace now in NodeJS console itself.